# With Rails 3 routes, how do you only allow a requests from 127.0.0.1?

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm writing an app where several of the routes should only be accessible from localhost. It looks like this is possible with the new routing system.

http://www.railsdispatch.com/posts/rails-3-makes-life-better

This has examples of restricting routes based on IP address, and setting up an IP address blacklist for your routes, but I'm interested in a whitelist with just one IP address.

It would be cool if something like this worked:

```
get "/posts" => "posts#show", :constraints => {:ip => '127.0.0.1'}
```

But it didn't. Am I just missing the right syntax?

Answer (score 15):

you can do this

```
get "/posts" => "posts#show", :constraints => {:ip => /127.0.0.1/}
```

or this

```
constraints(:ip => /127.0.0.1/) do
  get "/posts" => "posts#show"
end
```

Comment: Note that since IP6, I had to change it to `:ip => /127.0.0.1|::1/`. `::1` is IP6 localhost.

Answer (score 0):

following the example in Yehuda's post, you shoud create an approriate object to handle complex constraints. so, just editing that example could help. there's a line of code which checks if some ip is blacklisted:

```
!@ips.include?(request.remote_ip)
```

you should write similar logic (but simpler) that checks if request.remote_ip == 127.0.0.1